# Imports not working with Flask in Docker (no gunicorn!)

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a flask app, with Flask RestX, that works fine with `flask run` but has import issues with Docker. I've seen some questions and answers about this but they all involve Gunicorn, but **I'm not using Gunicorn**.

Here is my folder structure. I'm running the `docker-compose` file which uses the `flask.dev.dockerfile` as well as a Redis container.

[image]

So, I want to use my redis wrapper, `RedisDatabase`, from my `database.py` file. PyCharm inserts this as

```
from ivd_app.database import RedisDatabase
```

And the rest of the `__init__.py` file, in summary:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_restx import Api, Resource, fields

def create_app(db=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    if (db is None):
        db = RedisDatabase()

    api = Api(app, version='0.0.1', title='IVD')

    config_endpoint = api.namespace(
        'config', description='APIs to Send configuration to and from the Front End'
    )

    config_model = api.model('Configuration', {
        # the model
    })

    @config_endpoint.route('/')
    class ConfigurationEndpoint(Resource):

        @config_endpoint.expect(config_model, validate=True)
        def put(self):
            # the put endpoint

        def get(self):
            # the get endpoint

    return app

# if __name__ == "__main__":
#    create_app().run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

When I use `CMD flask run` from the dockerfile after setting the environment variables, the application runs. But for some reason I can't access the flask server, so instead I uncomment the lines at the bottom, since I know those work, and use `CMD python ivd_app/__init__.py` in the Dockerfile. But the container exits:

```
flask_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
flask_1  |   File "ivd_app/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
flask_1  |     from ivd_app.database import RedisDatabase
flask_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ivd_app'
```

If I remove the import statement and put the `RedisDatabase` class in the `__init__.py` file, the entire app works, of course. But I want to separate it into a different file.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Flask by defaults binds to `127.0.0.1` so if you use `CMD flask run` it'll reject connections from outside the container.

If I remember correctly you must either do

```
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0
CMD flask run
```

or

```
CMD flask run --host 0.0.0.0
```

As for the other method, I'd try

```
CMD python -m ivd_app
```

since you appear to try running a module rather than a standalone script.

Comment: Ooh this looks brilliant, and I'm trying your last option, but it's not working. As written it gives me `No module named ivd_app.__main__; 'ivd_app' is a package and cannot be directly executed` and if I specify `ivd_app/__init__.py` I get `Error while finding module specification for 'ivd_app/__init__.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ivd_app/__init__')`

Comment: The flask solution worked, though!